# Make 'value' of [key, value] Pair into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

I have a simple object I want to turn into key value pairs to display in a `SectionList`.

```
const DOBBY = {
  foo: 'bar',
  toto: ['hoge', 'piyo'],
};
```

I used `Objects.entries()` to turn it into an array of objects:

```
const toArray = Object.entries(DOBBY).map(([ title, data ]) => ({ title, data }));
```

So that I get back:

```
[
  { title: 'foo', data: 'bar' },
  { title: 'toto', data: ['hoge', 'piyo'] },
];
```

Right now `SectionList` splits `'bar'` into three rows. 
How do I put `'bar'` into an array so that I get:

```
[
 { title: 'foo', data: ['bar'] },
 { title: 'toto', data: ['hoge', 'piyo'] },
]
```

I think `Array.of()` will do it, but I don't know where to implement it, or whether there's something I can do with `.map()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply force nest `data` into a sub-array, and then flatten it using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

- When `data` is an array, `[data]` will be an array with a single element that is also an array, so `Array.flat` will flatten it into an array
- When `data` is a string, `[data]` will be an array of string, and `Array.flat` will preserve the way it is

```js
const DOBBY = {
  foo: 'bar',
  toto: ['hoge', 'piyo'],
};

const toArray = Object.entries(DOBBY).map(([ title, data ]) => ({ title, data: [data].flat() }));
console.log(toArray);
```

Of course, you can also  go for a slightly long winded way, but that means you don't unneedingly nest array within an array:

```js
const DOBBY = {
  foo: 'bar',
  toto: ['hoge', 'piyo'],
};

const toArray = Object.entries(DOBBY).map(([ title, data ]) => {
  return {
    title,
    data: Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data]
  };
});
console.log(toArray);
```

The `Array.prototype.flat()` method is of course slower, because you will be performing additional array nesting. That's a sacrifice you pay for readability. Also, for very small objects and arrays, this performance overhead is probably negligible:

https://jsperf.com/array-prototype-flat-vs-isarray/

```
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|               Test              | Chrome 80  | Firefox 74 | Safari 13  |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Array.prototype.flat() approach | 640k ops/s | 2.4m ops/s | 590k ops/s |
| Array.isArray approach          | 2.6m ops/s | 2.7m ops/s | 650k ops/s |
+---------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Terry. What's the detriment if I don't flatten and leave it at `data: [data]`?

Comment: You need to flatten it, otherwise you will get `[['hoge', 'piyo']]` (i.e. nested array)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it is an Array, if so just insert the data, if not put the data into an empty Array

```js
const DOBBY = {
  foo: 'bar',
  toto: ['hoge', 'piyo'],
};

const toArray = Object.entries(DOBBY)
.map(([title, data ]) => ({ title, data: Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data] }));
```

it worked for me, so i hope this helps :)